# Rails validates_uniqueness_of is causing an exponential number of queries. How do you optimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_options, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
   validates_associated :list_options

class ListOption < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => [:list_id]
```

When a new list is created along with lets say 10 list items in the controller:

```
@list = List.create(params[:list].merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

The database get queried individually to check each listOption to see if it is unique. Is there a way to optimize the above so the db doesn't keep getting hit to check every item?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like n queries, not x^n? How about taking the validation away and putting in a unique composite index, then handle the exception if thrown?

Comment: interesting problem, interesting suggestion. I wonder how `has_many :list_options, :uniq => true` on your List would behave in this case ? Or maybe you could drop the validates_associated, do a list_options.collect &:title and manually check the db yourself, like `ListOption.where(list_id: id, title: list_options.collect &:title).exists?`. Dont really know, why not ?

Comment: oh, but how to build a composite index if the List's id is not yet set  (List.new) ? maybe squeeze this in an after_save ?

Comment: How do you do a unique composite index and catch the error if thrown in rails?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a unique index inside your database.
First run `script/rails generate migration unique_index` to get a migration. It will be called something like db/migrate/20120313180200_unique_index.rb

Put this inside:

```
class UniqueIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_index(:list_options, [:list_id, :title], :unique => true)
  end

  def down
    remove_index(:list_options, :column => [:list_id, :title])
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` in your rails-root. This will fail if there already are duplicate titles as your database will immediately check that each combination of list_id and title is unique.

If you now try to save an duplicate entry into the database it will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception. To handle it try something like

```
begin
  ListOption.save
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  # Some handling code
  # use $! to access the exception for further details
end
```

Of cause you can also ignore these errors.

A side-effect of adding the unique-index to the database is, that queries to check whether a certain pair of list_id and title is stored inside the database, are speed up quite a bit, so you may be able to leave the uniqueness-check inside your model and still have a much better response time.